# Powershell Active Directory Account Attribute to a variable

Tags: powershell

Sorry for the newbie question. I am using Powershell 3 to get a list of all user accounts. I am trying to generate an output for accounts, either "Enabled" or "Disabled". I am able to get the account status code from active directory using:

```
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl");
```

That will display the correct account status code.

When I try to use an if statement on the value, I dont get any result. How do I put this value into a variable to use some logic with it?

In the end, my requirements are to have the output to an CSV file that I can send to HR and have them examin it and instead of a code I would like to have it say "Enabled" or "Disabled".

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The userAccountControl attribute is a *bitmap*, which means that each bit in the number represents a true (1) or false (0) value. Here is an example:

```
$ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 2
...
$accountDisabled = ($userObject.Properties["useraccountcontrol"][0] -band $_ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE) -ne 0
```

In this example the variable $accountDisabled will contain $TRUE if the account is disabled, or $FALSE otherwise. To check any other bits in the userAccountControl attribute, use the flag values documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772300.aspx and combine with **-band** operator as in this example. If not zero (**-ne 0**), the bit is set; if zero (**-eq 0**), the bit is not set. Another example would be to check if the "password never expires" bit is set; you could use code like this:

```
$ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 65536
...
$neverExpires = ($userObject.Properties["useraccountcontrol"][0] -band $ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD) -ne 0
```