# LDAP User enabled attribute PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filter, ldap

I know you can filter an LDAP search with

`-LDAPFilter "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"`

What I want to do is collect all users (enabled or disabled) and then
access an attribute that says whether this user is enabled or not.

Something along the lines of:

`Find-LdapObject -PropertiesToLoad objectSid, GivenName, Enabled | % {
     Write-Host $_.Enabled
}`

Problem is there is no Enabled in the LDAP-attributes.
Get-ADUser provides this attribute, and that is what we use
today, but it takes way too long with thousands of users.
Maybe there is a way to access the property that resides within
userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:?

```
$users = Find-LdapObject 
        -LdapConnection $domain 
        -searchFilter:("objectClass=User") 
        -searchBase $usersdn 
        -PropertiesToLoad objectSid, GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName,
                          mail, userPrincipalName, company, displayName,
                          whenCreated, title, adminCount, memberOf, userAccountControl,
                          objectClass, Mobile, Telephone, lastLogon 
        -BinaryProperties objectSid


foreach($user in $users) {

    #Extracts data from Ldap-Object
    try {
        #Does some converting
        $objectSid = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($user.objectSid,0)).Value
        $lastLogon = Get-Date -Date ([datetime]::FromFileTime($user.lastLogon)) -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        $whenCreated = [datetime]::ParseExact($user.whenCreated.Split('.')[0], 'yyyyMMddHHmmss',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

        #The magic is needed here
        if($user.userAccountControl -eq "1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2") {
            $enabled = 0
        } else {
            $enabled = 1
        }
```

All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `Get-ADUser` already returns this - `Get-ADUser -Filter * |Group-Object Enabled`

Comment: Thank you, but as stated in the question, using Get-ADUser is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid `Get-ADUser`?

Comment: Because using a direct LDAP-query is alot faster for some reason

Comment: Perhaps you're not aware that `Get-ADUser` uses LDAP "under the hood"? (It has a `-LDAPFilter` parameter, after all.)

Comment: @ifalso: get-aduser will use the same amount of time as LDAP query.

Comment: Answer without AD cmdlets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756409/

Comment: @Bill_Stewart sorry Bill, only just saw your linked answer

Comment: Okay, I accept that and with having done some quick testing I might have to agree too. Going to review what's taking so long in our scripts. Thank you though. Get-ADUser is the easier way to go for sure.

Comment: No problem @MathiasR.Jessen - I think this may be an XY problem anyway...

Answer (score 3):

> Problem is there is no Enabled in the LDAP-attributes

As the LDAP filter you've shown indicates, you need to check the value of `userAccountControl` for the presence of bit `2` to figure out whether the account is disabled or not - you can use the `-band` (bitwise AND) operator:

```
$Enabled = ($user.userAccount -band 2) -ne 2
```